# Save health,fun,coin after change state

Tags: javascript, android, phaser-framework

//Edit

I want to save the health,  coin, fun value after switching state and back state.

I created the game object/array:

```
game.yourGameData = {};
game.yourGameData.health = 100;
game.yourGameData.coin = 100;
game.yourGameData.fun = 100;
```

Next i define the value to params pet:

//set health

```
var health, fun, coin;


    health = this.game.yourGameData.health;
    fun = this.game.yourGameData.fun;
    coin = this.game.yourGameData.coin;

    //custom properties of the pet
    this.pet.customParams = {health, fun, coin};
```

And value is showing without error.
Now i open the subgame via function:

```
showtry: function()
{
    this.game.state.start('brick_destro_game');
},
```

When i finish the subgame and switch back to main state the health have value 100.

Switch back state function:

```
clickOnActionExit: function()
    {
        this.game.state.start('GameState');
    },
```

What i want to see:
Pet stared at 100 health, next he dont eat anything. Health is droped to 70.
I switch state to subgame and play. I finish game and back to main state.
Pet should'ev 70 health, but its reset to 100.

[All project code here](https://github.com/futer/pandachiifull/tree/master/main)

[game](https://github.com/futer/pandachiifull/blob/master/main/js/main.js)

Comment: Where do you set the `yourGameData` object? if it is set within the GameState state, it will be reset everytime you start it

Comment: Check the file: game i just add it to post

Comment: ok, you have `this.pet`... but there is it defined? within the start method of the state? Is `this` the `game` or the state or anything else?

Comment: pet is defined on create function. this.pet = ..........
I will defined it in other place. I will check ;D

Comment: Ok, i change the place where pet is definded to "global variable".
Still its the same.

Answer (score 1):

Like you mentioned you can either keep the data out-of-band (globally) or a method that I like using which I feel is better than global variables is attach a new object to the 'game' for saving your data.  This will persist with the game everywhere.

For example

```
this.game.yourGameData = {};
this.game.yourGameData.health = 70;
this.game.yourGameData.cons = 100;
```

Comment: i try your method, but still doesn't work. Again it start from 100 every time.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that these values are being reset by the state every time the create function is executed, you should implement something like the following:

```
var state = {
  create: function () {
    if (!game.pet) {
      var health, fun, coin;

      health = this.game.yourGameData.health;
      fun = this.game.yourGameData.fun;
      coin = this.game.yourGameData.coin;

      //custom properties of the pet
      game.pet={customParams : {health, fun, coin}};
    }
  },
  update: {...}
}
```

Make sure you remove the attribute game.pet when the pet "dies" in order to reset the values when starting again.

Comment: I try this but now i have error msg:

`main.js:84 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'customParams' of undefined`

`main.js:199 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'health' of undefined`

code update in github

Comment: Fixed, the problem was that pet did not exist

Comment: i have other error :D
`main.js:183 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'health' of undefined refreshStats `

`main.js:201 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'health' of undefined`

This cant read health and other  ; /